# Как правильно сделать дамп БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, debian

У меня есть работающий сайт Django на nginx и gunicorn, как правильно сделать дамп базы данных? Нужно ли отключать nginx, я пытался сделать просто дамп возкла ошибка невозможно подключиться к серверу:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "mydb" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "0.0.0.0" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Вместо 0.0.0.0 мой айпи. Как правильно поступить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вы запускаете pg_dump в консоли этого же сервера?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да

Comment: `Connection refused` отвечает ОС. По этому адресу с этим номером порта никто не принимает соединения. Проверяйте на каком порту база запущена, запущена ли вовсе, какие адреса слушает. `ss -l` подскажет какие сокеты зарегистрированы с точки зрения ОС.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, проверьте в postgresql.conf директиву `listen_addresses`. По умолчанию она содержит значение 'localhost', поэтому к СУБД невозможно подключиться на адрес отличный от 127.0.0.1. При необходимости измените её. Во-вторых, в [pg_hba.conf](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/auth-pg-hba-conf) нужно разрешить подключения по сети. После изменения обеих настроек СУБД необходимо перезапустить.

Comment: Перезапускать базу для изменений pg_hba не нужно, достаточно reload.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, заработало, но при restore возникают ошибки что таблицы уже сущетвуют, это нормально, или оно должно пересоздавать?

Comment: При формировании дампа можно указать ключи, чтобы в дамп не попадали DDL-инструкции, или наоборот указать ключ, чтобы добавились инструкции удаления существующих отношений.

Comment: И при если к примеру у меня есть такая же БД на ново сервере, установятся ли туда обьекты БД, заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/app-pgrestore я так понимаю нужно использовать -c --clean?